# Is there a way to obtain the length of the cell's subtitle (detailedTextLabel)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, subtitle

as mentioned in the question, I would like to obtain the length of the subtitle (topic.context) and use it to make certain decisions (see my code snippet below)

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = topic.context;
NSString *fanLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i fans",topic.num_fans];

if (topic.context && ![topic.context isEqual:[NSNull null]] && topic.context.length > 46)
{
    thisFanLabel.frame = CGRectMake(320 - 150, -10, 100, 44);
}
else
{
    thisFanLabel.frame = CGRectMake(320 - 150, 0, 100, 44);
}
```

Basically, I want to know when the subtitle will reach a certain length so that I can adjust the fan label to be shifted upwards (as seen in the diagram below). Currently the fans label is being overlapped by the subtitle, I want to be able to shift the label upwards when this happens.

[image]

So what would be the best way to obtain the accurate length of the subtitle?

Comment: Surely it would look terrible if you did that? Why not just have a shorter label and truncate any long text, or put the subtitle text on to two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the size of a string with a certain font by using the following lines:

```
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(9999,9999);

UILabel *myLabel = cell.detailTextLabel;
CGSize sizeOfString = [myLabel.text sizeWithFont:myLabel.font 
                        constrainedToSize:maxSize 
                        lineBreakMode:myLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

In "sizeOfString" you should now have the size of your detailLabel.

Answer (score 0):

See `NSString`'s `-sizeWithFont:` and related methods.